# Implement capistrano in ruby on rails having database MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, capistrano

I want to implement capistrano in my ruby on rails project. I am using MongoDB as database . 
I install capistrano gem.

```
capify .
[add] writing './Capfile'
[add] writing './config/deploy.rb'
[done] capified!
```

It gives me file deploy.rb inside the Config. What should i do inside. so where do i have to put mongoid.yml ? Working code is helpful for me to do or some hints is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You should first be clear about why you want to `implement capistrano` :-)

[Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) is a tool for making deployments easier - it allows for executing commands in multiple remote machines, via ssh.

For a default installation of a Rails App with mongodb, you don't need to have anything related to mongodb in the capistrano `deploy.rb` file.

You would add some mongodb stuff in this file if there is some mongodb related task that you want to accomplish every time the code is deployed to the remote servers.

Example: Here is a capistrano recipe example [to synchronize local mongodb with production](http://www.idolhands.com/ruby-on-rails/guides-tips-and-tutorials/a-capistrano-task-for-synchronizing-your-local-mongodb-with-production)

I would recommend that you familiarize yourself with the basics of capistrano by watching [the railscast episode on capistrano tasks.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/133-capistrano-tasks)

Comment: Here i am fetching my project from github in 3 machine. Each time some update in project i have to push pull in github . Then again other users using this project should follow push pull then  restart to be updated. I am new in Capistrano. Here is it useful when i use capistrano and what makes me easy to implement capistrano here?

Comment: Yup, capistrano is a good choice for automating the process of deploying the code from github to the 3 machines.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But what thing i have to do to work it. Can you guide me also how does it work?

Comment: The rails cast link I put above is a good place to start. Also check out this video "Basic Deployment with Capistrano" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qn5KVGB9Xk

Comment: Yes i already did look that railscast episode. But i am confuse because i am using Mongodb. and when i use capistrano in my case what benefits I will get. May be my question is stupid ..

Answer (score 0):

Put mongoid.yml in /config, and type `cap deploy` in /.